# Find all tuple occurrences in arbitrary term

Tags: erlang

I've got an arbitrary term containing unknown well-structured erlang data. I need to find all occurrences of a tuple {atom, _} any where in this term.

Pattern matching relies on knowing which structure contains your data, yet I don't.

Example from which I need to extract

```
  [
    {description, ""},
    {applications, [
      kernel,
      stdlib,
      ssl
    ]},
    {env, [
      {is_enabled, true},
      {jos, {atom, "2o3urglk3ugr"}},
      {fss_pool, {
        [
          {ja, 10}
        ],
        [
          {host, {atom, "fkejbkjfb"}},
          {port, 6000}
        ]}
      }
    ]}
  ]}.
```

Is there a general pattern matching way to traverse an arbitrary term?

Comment: So your data structure start with a `[` and ends with a `}`.  Can you explain what that's called?  A `luple`?

Comment: Is your data always a list?

Comment: Can a term in the data be: `{atom, {1, 2, {atom, 3, 4}}`?  Or, is it always `{atom, List}`?

Comment: it should be {atom, _} - any tuple matching that should be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  You'd have to treat each kind of data structure you want to traverse specially.  Something like:

```
traverse({atom, Value}) ->
    %% found it!
    [{atom, Value}];
traverse(List) when is_list(List) ->
    lists:flatmap(fun traverse/1, List);
traverse(Tuple) when is_tuple(Tuple) ->
    lists:flatmap(fun traverse/1, tuple_to_list(Tuple));
traverse(Map) when is_map(Map) ->
    lists:flatmap(fun traverse/1, maps:to_list(Map));
traverse(_Other) ->
    %% not the value we're looking for
    [].
```

Comment: Using `lists:flatmap/1` for tuple and maps is unnecessary *optimization*. You can just call `traverse/1` for `tuple_to_list/1` or `maps:to_list/1` result.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a complete answer as I just installed OTP 22.0, but you can turn the above mentioned value to binary and then use RE to find all required matches.

E.g.:

```
X = ...,
B  = term_to_binary(X),
{ok, MP} = re:compile(<<"atom">>, [extended]),
{match, Res} = re:run(B, MP, [{capture, all, index}]),
ok = io:fwrite("BX: ~p ~p~n ~p", [B, MP, Res]).
```

The options for re:compile & re:run aren't exactly what you required, and the regex itself should be expanded to include the value after the atom :/

(Due to time constraints I cannot give a copy&paste answer, but I did something similar to parse textual logs from another program and find what I needed to. I hope this points you to another optional work-through.)

Comment: started with this, yet regex won't do something like {atom, {sdsd,sdsd}} etc